# Javascript memory leak detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management

I've written a very simple script to query the length of a list in redis and output memory usage.

It seems that the "heap used" memory is running higher over time.

Does this infer a memory leak, and how can this code be changed to prevent this?

Output:

```
[2020-01-02 16:59:09] Queue length > 0
[2020-01-02 16:59:09] Test queue length is 121
[2020-01-02 16:59:09] Heap total: 18.23MB, Heap Used: 8.43MB
[2020-01-02 16:59:11] Queue length > 0
[2020-01-02 16:59:11] Test queue length is 121
[2020-01-02 16:59:11] Heap total: 18.73MB, Heap Used: 8.70MB
[2020-01-02 16:59:13] Queue length > 0
[2020-01-02 16:59:13] Test queue length is 121
[2020-01-02 16:59:13] Heap total: 18.73MB, Heap Used: 8.72MB
...
[2020-01-02 17:03:53] Queue length > 0
[2020-01-02 17:03:53] Test queue length is 121
[2020-01-02 17:03:53] Heap total: 18.73MB, Heap Used: 11.17MB
```

Code:

```
const Redis           = require('ioredis');
const redis           = new Redis();
const dateformat      = require('dateformat');
const log             = console.log;


console.log = function () {
  let output = ['[',dateformat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")];
  output.push(']');
  output = [output.join('')]
  output = output.concat([].slice.call(arguments));
  log.apply(console,
            output
          );
}

function loop() {
   redis.llen('test').then( (queue_length) => {
       if (queue_length > 0) {
           console.log("Queue length > 0")
           }
       console.log(`Test queue length is ${queue_length}`)
       let m = process.memoryUsage()
       console.log(`Heap total: ${(m['heapTotal']/1024/1024).toFixed(2)}MB, Heap Used: ${(m['heapUsed']/1024/1024).toFixed(2)}MB`);
   })
}

setInterval(loop, 2000)
```

EDIT:

Eventually I saw what I can only assume is garbage collection:

```
[2020-01-02 17:05:41] Queue length > 0
[2020-01-02 17:05:41] CDR queue length is 121
[2020-01-02 17:05:41] Heap total: 13.73MB, Heap User: 8.63MB
```

I'm unsure if a leak is still inferred as the memory continues to rise, then falls post garbage collection. Is it best practice to clear variable assignments during this `setInterval` loop, or just leave it to GC?

Comment: There are some use cases for manually clearing a variable that points to a very large data structure, but mostly in Javascript you just let the GC do its thing and make sure you don't retain references to large data structures that are no longer needed in permanent variables (variables declared in lasting scopes like at the top level) or accumulate data you no longer need in structures like an array.  FYI, clearing a reference to a large data structure does not delete it from memory at that time - it just makes it eligible for GC when GC decides to run.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, yet another SO question you've answered of mine very simply! I believe this comment answers the question succinctly, if you want to post it as the answer I will mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some use cases for manually clearing a variable that points to a very large data structure, but mostly in Javascript you just let the GC do its thing and make sure you don't retain references to large data structures that are no longer needed in permanent variables (variables declared in lasting scopes like at the top level) or accumulate data you no longer need in structures like an array.

FYI, clearing a reference to a large data structure does not delete it from memory at that time - it just makes it eligible for GC when GC decides to run (if no other variables are pointing at the same data).

---

There are a few types of situations in Javascript to keep an eye out for that can surprise people and this is often because a function scope in Javascript and the local variables in that scope can live long, long after the function itself has finished executing.

Here's a simple example:

```
function startTimer() {
    let bigVar = someGiantDataStructure;
    return setInterval(function() {
        if (someCondition) {
            ++bigVar.someProperty;
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }, 1000);
}

let intervalID = startTimer();
```

So, even though `startTimer()` runs and completes, it starts the interval timer which continues to regularly call its callback.  Because its theoretically possible for the callback to still reference `bigVar`, the data that `bigVar` points to will never be garbage collected until someone stops the interval timer.

So, if something happens in your processing of the timer and you know that `someCondition` will never be true again or the contents of `bigVar` will never be needed again, but the interval timer continues for other reasons, then it would make sense to do something like `bigVar = null;` to allow the data it points to to be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @AndrewWhite - I added a situation to look out for to my answer.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, thanks for clarifying! I would assume finishing execution of the script would also clean up this allocation and that specifically clearing the interval or variable is not required pre-exit?

Comment: @AndrewWhite - When the node.js process exists, all the Javascript memory will be freed (along with all memory used by the process) so no manual clearing of anything is required when the app exits. Stopping the interval is not required either.  An interval timer like shown above will cause the process to not automatically exit (as node.js thinks there's still code doing something), but if you manually call `process.exit()`, it will exit and all memory used by node.js will be automatically returned to the OS.  No shut-down cleanup of memory is required.